# program that works in Unity play mode does not work in Build and run

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I'm trying to make VR/AR in unity.
It contain recognizing hand gesture
It works well in Oculus Link (Unity Play mode) but somehow unity can't recognize my recorded hand gesture in build and run.

leftHand.GetFingerIsPinching(OVRHand.HandFinger.Index) is working but all my custom gestures are not working

I checked all my log but I have no idea what should I do

I tryed to initialize my code in awake. but it failed